# Display .TXT files in a different font in CLI

Tags: command-line, fonts, ansi

I am into BBSing in 2020. Bulletin Boards use ANSI graphics, which arent displayed correctly in current terminals... I use 'iconv' to change cp437 to utf8 and display .ANS files correctly.

However, I am getting into Amiga ASCII art. This art is just in regular .TXT or .ASC format, but uses Amiga fonts because Amiga fonts look different when drawing art with just the character set.

I need to display these .TXT/.ASC files in either Amiga Topaz or Amiga MicroKnight fonts... is there a way to get that correctl Topaz/MicroKnight font output in a terminal? I basically want to issue a command at the CLI and have those .TXT/.ASC files display with the correct font.

I have an editor that I can do this with, but don't know the CLI command to display a file in a certain font.

Thanks for any help.

BONUS QUESTION;
Is there a way to have a terminal natively show ANSI graphics correctly? ANSI graphics like the ones found on [www.16colo.rs](http://www.16colo.rs) .

Comment: Maybe you can use a virtual Amiga system. You can search the internet for 'virtual amiga' (without quotes).

Comment: I use ambian to boot directly into AmiBerry on a raspberry pi, and yes can view the correct fonts that way. However I want an option to doso in Linux CLI terminal, where I do my ansi editing. 

Thanks for the suggestion tho, it is valid

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/rewtnull/amigafonts) help?